# WPF binding from ListBox ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, datatemplate

I have a problem binding from `ListBox` `Itemtemplate` that contains an `Expander` with its own `HeaderTemplate` and `ContentTemplate`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Feeds}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Content="{Binding Text}" 
                          Header="{Binding Title}">

                    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>

                    <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Expander.ContentTemplate>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The PublishDate and ImageURL bindings don't work and I'd like to bind them to properties in the object Feed:

```
Public Class Feed
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property PublishDate As DateTime
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property ImageURL As String
End Class
```

I tried `FindAncestor` in the binding to find the `ListBoxItem` but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Content of the Expander serves as the DataContext for the ContentTemplate and the Header for the HeaderTemplate.

Set Content="{Binding}" and Header="{Binding}" instead. This sets the DataContext of both templates to the DataContext of the ListBoxItem (i.e. a Feed).